# AAC license needed to play AAC stream on Android app?

Tags: android, streaming, aac

I don't understand the fee question on AAC streaming.
I read that if i need to use decoding libraries (like [aacdecoder-android](https://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/)), since Android doesen't support AAC streams natively, i need to pay a fee, but i don't understand why.
Did I misunderstood it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core Android supports AAC-LC, HE-AACv1 (AAC+) and HE-AACv2 (enhanced AAC+) decoding natively, so you can don't buy any additional libraries for these profiles. In many cases that's more than needed for your tasks. If you want to play files encoded via other profiles - you should check license restrictions and may be pay fee.

Comment: Do you know the fee cost for AAC decoding as AAC streaming is not supported natively by Android?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct, if you use the native AAC libraries in Android, you don't have to pay the license fee, the device manufacturer already paid the fee.
VIA administers the licensing of AAC, you can get details and pricing here: http://www.vialicensing.com/licensing/aac-faq.aspx